# is it posible with DPFP .Net library to change the purpouse of a FeatureSet from verifcation to enrrollment?

Tags: .net, fingerprint

Best regards, Im using DPFP.Gui.Verification.VerificationControl to capture fingers with the purpose of verify. If them exist in a database, brign them to my window, otherwise I have to enroll them.

Like the DPFP's documentation says, When I want to enrroll a finger print
I have to pass four FeatureSet objects to an Enrollment object specifing those FeatureSets are for enrollment purpose (DataPurpose.Enrollment)

What I want to do is use the same FeatureSet send by the OnComplete event of the control and give it four times to Enrollment object. The problem is the FeatureSet sending has DataPurpose.Verification (what I need is DataPurpose.Ready) and that throws me an exception ("Incomplete enrollment").

So if exist a way to change the FeatureSet's DataPurpose or maybe create a new FeatureSet object with the first one like I have saw it's posible create it with a Sample oject. That could solve my problem n__n

...Or maybe could you guys give me an other way to do what I want to get.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another FeatureSet variable with Enrollment Purpose using the same Sample Variable.

Comment: Can you elaborate please?